# Redux state is updated but UI is not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created simple app to add user using redux and antd library. When user is added I am trying to show success message. I am able to get that updated message in state but when I alert that message it shows blank. When I again click the button then it shows success message in alert.

I have created codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-waterfall-v04g9

Please help me out, I am quite new to react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what possibly happened
- since your callback function is synchronous, eventhough the addUser function is placed before alert function, it is not a guarenty that it will execute before it.

solution is to make your function asynchronous as follows to guaranty that the user is added and hence state updated (with the user and the message you are displaying) before the alert is fired. make sure to save changes and refresh the sandbox to test it.

```
handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
  if (!err) {
    await this.props.addUser(values);
    alert(this.props.message);
  }
});
```